Instragram API throws error when using the graph API
My instagram app is verified, the business is verified but I am still getting errors.
$url = 'https://graph.instagram.com/'.$data->user_id.'?fields=id,username&access_token='.$data->access_token;
echo "<li>".$url."</li>";

I can get the user;s ID and the access token from the API but this should generate a URL where I can grab the username but the error I am getting is:

"{"error":{"message":"Unsupported request - method type:
get","type":"IGApiException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"AdB2aDtSLWMTn0aB5PTyQ5j"}}"

Any help would be much appreciated. I have been at this for days trying different API endpoints etc.

FYI: How do I format my posts?

The error says that GET methods are not permitted. What documentation are you following?
